# Running Caffe creates high load over ksoftirqd/0

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, caffe

I'm running Caffe using python on AWS.

The scripts uses the GPU, uploads an existing model, and checks the output of it per image URL.

On the first few tries the script ran well. Than it stuck on a few different phases at each time.

Using 'top' I could see that `ksoftirqd/0` gets about 93% of the CPU when the process is stuck.

I don't think there is a bug in my script, because originally it ran well no the server. When I reboot the server, sometimes it helps. But later we get the same problem.

Killing all python process on the server doesn't help. Only rebootting it.

Any ideas what I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are experiencing a [very high network load](https://askubuntu.com/a/7919).
What exactly are you trying to download from URLs?
Are there any other processes running at the same time on the machine?

It is difficult to diagnose your problem without the specifics of your script.

Comment: Hi,
There are not other processes.
Currently it stuck after the following cmds:
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
    net = caffe.Net(os.path.join(caffe_root, configs['prototxt']), 
                    os.path.join(caffe_root, configs['caffemodel']),
                    caffe.TEST)
    transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})

Gets stuck also when I use local jpg instead of URL's.

Thanks

Comment: @Tal (a) you are not using GPU if you are `caffe.set_mode_cpu()`. (b) what is the input layer of your net? can you post the prototxt you are using?

Comment: Sorry, 
I copied the code from my computer directly, where it's set on CPU. On the server it's the exact same code with caffe.set_mode_gpt()

Comment: I used to experience high load on a GPU EC2 machine due to bad CUDA driver installations. The load was caused by AWS monitoring services clashing with the bad CUDA drivers. Are you sure your machine is properly set?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. We reinstalled CUDA, and CAFFE, and its's working well now.